# Is there any standard for negotiating token-based authentication in HTTP?

Tags: http, rest, http-authentication

I know about Basic and Digest HTTP authentication, but these assume the use of a username/password combination. I'm developing a HTTP-based API wherein authentication is done through a token. I'm wondering whether there's any standard for how the server should solicit the token through the `WWW-Authenticate` header and for how the client should send it through the `Authorization` header.

I know there's the proposed [“HTTP Authentication: Token Access Authentication”](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-hammer-http-token-auth-01) which I think covers what I had in mind (and which [seems to be used in Rails](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/HttpAuthentication/Token.html)?); but as far as I can tell, the proposal has never progressed to a “standard”.

Is there any other standardized approach?

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at these:

- [OAuth 2](http://oauth.net/2/)
- [OpenID](http://openid.net/) (used by StackOverflow to log in with Google / Facebook / Yahoo).

Comment: But they're built on top of HTTP, not using the built-in headers he's asking about.

Comment: @Rup You're right: they are built *on top of* HTTP. But is it relevant? OAuth does use HTTP headers including, but not limited to, `WWW-Authenticate` and `Authorization`. In fact, [HTTP Token Access Authentication draft](http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-hammer-http-token-auth-01) (which seems to be what the OP had in mind) was submitted by the OAuth Working Group (see [mailing list archives](http://www.ietf.org/mail-archive/web/oauth/current/msg00872.html)). I'm pretty sure OpenID uses HTTP headers too. I think these 2 open standards may fit the OP needs.